# User session in facebook messenger bot

Tags: facebook, session, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

In normal web application we maintain session by sending UserID/sessionID/tokenID via cookie or as querystring parameter or in HTTP request in header.

How can we have a session when creating a chatbot using facebook messenger? This will be helpful in getting the context of the conversation.

From the documentation there is `metadata` field in the message object which can be set.

> Metadata is a custom string that will be re-delivered to webhook listeners

Can this be used for maintaining the session or is there a better option?

Comment: The page-scoped user id is part of the data you receive.

Answer (score 0):

As [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1427878/cbroe) commented, you already have the page-scoped user id on `entry.messaging.sender.id` property on the receiving JSON request, which can work as a session identifier for each user interacting with your bot.